# Getting the same output from parallel stages in jenkins scripted pipelines

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to create parallel stages in jenkins pipeline for say with this example

```
node {
 stage('CI') {
   script {
doDynamicParallelSteps()
   }

 }
}

def doDynamicParallelSteps(){
 tests = [:]
 for (f in ["Branch_1", "Branch_2", "Branch_3"]) {
   tests["${f}"] = {
     node {
       stage("${f}") {
         echo "${f}"
       }
     }
   }
 }
 parallel tests
}
```

I'm expecting to see "Branch_1", "Branch_2", "Branch_3" and instead I'm getting "Branch_3", "Branch_3", "Branch_3"

[image]

I don't understand why. Can you please help ?

Comment: In groovy, the variable `f` in `for` loop is mutable. That means each iteration of the loop uses the same instance of the variable `f`. 
Modify the inner loop to create a new variable for each iteration and then use it in the rest the following command of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** On the classic view, the stage names are displaying the last value of the variable `${f}`. Also, all the echo are echoing the same value. You need to change the loop.

**Long Answer:** Jenkins does not allow to have multiple stages with the same name so this could never happen successfully :)

On your example, you can see it fine on Blue Ocean:

[image: Blue Ocean Replicated]

Also, on console output, the names are right too. 
On Jenkins classic view, the stage names have the last value of the variable `${f}`. The last value is being printed on the classic view for the stage name, and all the `echo` are the same.

**Solution:** Change your loop. This worked fine for me.

```
node {
 stage('CI') {
   script {
    doDynamicParallelSteps()
   }
 }
}

def void doDynamicParallelSteps(){
    def branches = [:] 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
        int index=i, branch = i+1
        branches["branch_${branch}"] = { 
            stage ("Branch_${branch}"){ 
                node {
                    sh "echo branch_${branch}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    parallel branches
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with closures and iteration, but in the end this might fix it:

```
 for (f in ["Branch_1", "Branch_2", "Branch_3"]) {
   def definitive_name = f
   tests[definitive_name] = {
```